# Angular HttpClient - Failed to pass params for the response of Blob type

Tags: angular, typescript, http, angular-httpclient

My background API is to generate Excel. But when I set parameter passing in Angular, passing parameters in the console does not work. How do I pass parameters for blob-type requests?

```
ExportMyTicket():Observable<Blob> {
  let params = new HttpParams();

  //Parameter passing failure;
  params.append('myParam', '111');

  return this.http.get<Blob>(`${this.exportExcelUrl}`,
    { params, responseType: 'blob' as 'json' })
}
```

I tried to pass the parameters on the front end, but I couldn't pass them, no matter how I set the parameters.

Answer (score 1):

From [`HttpParams` description](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpParams#description)

> This class is immutable; all mutation operations return a new instance.

1. You should reassign to `params` with the result returned from `.append()`.
2. Remove the `as: 'json'` from `responseType: 'blob'`.

```
ExportMyTicket():Observable<Blob> {
  let params = new HttpParams();

  //Parameter passing failure;
  params = params.append('myParam', '111');

  return this.http.get<Blob>(`${this.exportExcelUrl}`,
    { params: params, responseType: 'blob' })
}
```

Comment: It is my grammar problem. Thank you for your help.